# why the query2 is not accepting and giving me TypeError

Tags: python

```
class saveRecord:
    def __init__(self,name,email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

query1 = input('name ')
query2 = input('email ')

save1 = saveRecord(query1)
save2 = saveRecord(query2)

print(save1.name)
print(save2.email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class saveRecord:
    def __init__(self,name,email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

query1 = input('name ')
query2 = input('email ')

save1 = saveRecord(query1, query2)

print(save1.name)
print(save1.email)
```

- Note in your `__init__` you have two arguments.